# Did Apple remove HTML5 cache offline viewing from iOS devices?

Tags: html, caching, offline, cache-manifest, html5-appcache

I made an HTML5 "webapp" for my company back in April, and at that point, I was able to place is on the homescreen of iPhones and iPads, and save it as a bookmark for offline viewing (Android and BB as well, but those are not presenting problems).

Now, 6 months later, I attempt to load the pages, and for my iPhone and iPad, the homescreen buttons will not load, but the bookmarks still function.

Is there a glitch preventing the homescreen buttons to load when there is no signal?

(yes, I am aware that there are questions/answers from years back, but I am looking for an updated answer)

Here is my manifest:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

    #v1.3

    CACHE:
    nyipad.css
    nymobile.css
    expoLogo.png
    schedule.jpg
    contact.jpg
    fav.png
```

Like I said, this DOES work with Android, BB, and iOS bookmarks, and only fails with the iOS homescreen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

iOS6 [made several moves](http://taitems.tumblr.com/post/24936855546/what-ios-6-mobile-safari-offers-front-end-devs) to make browsing faster and on the way [introduced some bugs](http://www.devthought.com/2012/09/22/understanding-the-ios6-ajax-bugs/) and [some more than involve your case](http://blog.nsbasic.com/?p=928).

On iOS6 the way the Homescreen manages data is quite different. It doesn't share data with Web App data, but uses a separate storage for Homescreen data alongside the native apps.

In short this means that:

- Data in Homescreen apps is lost when upgrading to iOS6
- Different user data (appcache, local storage, SQLite etc.) when using the Web app and Homescreen app
- Homescreen app data are treated like native app data and are safe from the "Clear data" function of the browser

Source:
http://blog.nsbasic.com/?p=928

Comment: thanks...any word on iOS 4 or 5? My iPad isn't updated, but is still struggling with WebApps.